# Apparently inconsistent segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack

WARNING: I know I'm not giving any context to this code, and in general this is extremely necessary, but I think that due to the nature of the error/situation it's not necessary and it would unnecessarily obscure things. That being said, if you suggest me to edit the question to add context and definitions to my code, I will of course do it.

In the following code

```
    Person *root = list[0];
    Element start = {root, NULL};
    Stack Q = {&start};
    i = 0;
    Element *next_elem = NULL;
    Element *first = NULL;
    int cn;
    Person *p = NULL;
    puts("Starting stack process...");
    while(Q.start != NULL) 
    {   // process the first element, look at their info and children
        printf("Name: %s\n", Q.start ->prsn ->name);
        cn = Q.start ->prsn ->cn;
        printf("Nº of children: %i\n", cn);
        // look at their children and put them in the stack
        first = Q.start;
        
        for(i = 0; i < cn; i++)
        {   if((next_elem = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element))) == NULL) return 1;
            next_elem ->prsn = first ->prsn ->children[i]; 
            first -> next = next_elem;
            first = next_elem;
        } 
        Q.start = Q.start -> next;
    }
```

I get the following error

```
Process 5864 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000de0 GTree_DFS`main at GTree_DFS.c:101:32
   98           first = Q.start;
   99           for(i = 0; i < cn; i++)
   100          {   if((next_elem = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element))) == NULL) return 1;
-> 101              next_elem ->prsn = first ->prsn ->children[i]; 
   102              first -> next = next_elem;
   103              first = next_elem;
   104          } 
Target 0: (GTree_DFS) stopped.
```

Which is solved by changing the for loop condition from  `i < cn` to  `i < cn - 1`. So this should mean that the problem is that I'm going out of bounds right? Well no, because if I modify the code adding a line like `p = first ->prsn ->children[3];` before the for loop, it does not raise any error:

```
Process 5897 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100000ddf GTree_DFS`main at GTree_DFS.c:101:32
   98           p = first ->prsn ->children[3]; // No segfault here
   99           for(i = 0; i < cn; i++)
   100          {   if((next_elem = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(Element))) == NULL) return 1;
-> 101              next_elem ->prsn = first ->prsn ->children[i]; // Segfault here
   102              first -> next = next_elem;
   103              first = next_elem;
   104          } 
Target 0: (GTree_DFS) stopped.
```

If the segfault is not due to the `i` index, then why would the change `i < cn`to  `i < cn - 1` solve it? Isn't this error inconsistent?

Comment: The title's invisible subtext is "undefined behaviour". It's very common for the behaviour to change when you make apparently harmless changes to the code.

Comment: Should I add undefined behaviour to the title?

Comment: There is no need.

Comment: @CMB In that case your title will become your answer.  And the answer is "undefined behavior".

Comment: I am always suspisious of `pointer1 -> pointer2 -> member` without any check on the intermediate pointer value, but it is not easy from the incomplete code to see what is happening. You should find out exactly what is causing the segfault: `NULL` pointer, uninitialised pointer, dangling pointer, etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane however if that was the problem, why would changing the bounds of "i" solve it? That's what I can't understand

Comment: What is undefined is the result of the coding error, and small changes can shift where the damage is caused, or seen. The damage isn't always done by the nearby instructions: when a bullet hits a tree next to you, you need to look elsewhere for the gun.

Comment: If you know the problem is (probably) something to do with the linked list structure, you should be printing - or inspecting in the debugger - all those pointers, checking every de-reference and address. You could also try building with a sanitizer or running with valgrind. There's no way to help without seeing the real data structure state at the point it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I may be completely confused but the loop seems wrong.

You allocate `next_elem` in line 100,
and it seems to have a member which is
a pointer, called `prsn`

But during allocation, that pointer has no value, so during the next pass through the loop
it will be used     (look at line 101, LHS) via the `first` variable, which leads to unpredictable results...